# Kitsune - Favored Class : Rogue

Tags: pathfinder-1e

In the book it states the following:

Rogue: The Rogue gaines 1/6 of a new rogue talent.

My question is what does that actually mean in english?

Answer (score 8):

When a [kitsune](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/uncommon-races/arg-kitsune) [rogue](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue) picks the favored class option *The rogue gains ⅙ of a new rogue talent* a sixth time, the kitsune rogue gains a new, extra [rogue talent](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue#TOC-Rogue-Talents) of the player's choice.

That is, to get the new, extra rogue talent, a kitsune must take six levels of rogue and pick that favored class option for each of those rogue levels, receiving no benefits for having picked that favored class bonus prior to picking that favored class option a sixth time.

To be clear, until that favored class option has been picked a sixth time—for example, when that favored class option is picked the first through fifth times and after that favored class option is picked the seventh through eleventh times—the favored class option has no appreciable effect.